# How can i split address in streetname and streetnumber in nifi?

Tags: java, regex, apache-nifi

I'm trying to split a given address (Muster Straße 114 a) in streetname and streetnumber. I'm working with nifi. The situation is the following: i have a FlowFile-Attribute (order_address) which has as FlowFile-content e.g Muster Straße 114 a, and i need to split it into sepereate attributes. 
I tried

```
 /\A\s*(?:?:\s*)?(\pN+[a-zA-Z]?(?:\s*[-\/\pP]\s*\pN+[a-zA-Z]?)*)\s*,?\s*(?P(?:[a-zA-Z]\s*|\pN\pL{2,}\s\pL)\S[^,#]*?(?<!\s))s*(?:(?:[,\/]|(?=\#))\s*(?!\s*\.(?P(?!\s).*?))? | ?:(?P.*?),\s*(?=.*[,\/]))??!\s*\.)(?P[^0-9#]\s*\S(?:[^,#](?!\b\pN+\s))*?(?<!\s))\s*[\/,]?\s*(?:\sNo[.:])?\s*(?P\pN+\s*-?[a-zA-Z]?(?:\s*[-\/\pP]?\s*\pN+(?:\s*[\-a-zA-Z])?)*|[IVXLCDM]+(?!.*\b\pN+\b))(?<!\s)\s*(?:(?:[,\/]|(?=\#)|\s)\s*(?!\s*No\.)\s*(?P(?!\s).*?))?)\s*\Z/xu
```

but it's not working for me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far?

Comment: use editors to debug your regexp. for example: https://regex101.com/r/wEhdWp/1

Answer (score 1):

If we'd like to just separate our addresses into two parts, one including the digits and one without, we could find several expressions that'd cover this rule, such as:

```
(.*?)([\d].*)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pQnO4d/1/)

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "(.*?)([\\d].*)";
final String string = "Muster Straße 114 a";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In nifi, you can use the Nifi Expression language to manipulate FlowFile-Attributes. So i used the UpadateAttribute-Processor, to create the new FlowFile-Attributes street_name and streed_number.

I used the replaceAll method with a simple regex, to get streetnumber and streetname.

```
^(\D*)(?:.*)
^\D*(.*)
```

This two regex did it.

Here you find the screenshot of the processor:

[image: 1]